# Containing single data in multiple containers

Tags: c++, vector, alias

I've lots of data to acquire and process (near a million) and i don't wanna copy or move it along the whole program.

Let me describe the situation with an example. I have a Vector with 100.000 elements. And i want to keep the track of the time when these elements were inserted into the vector. So, it's a good idea to keep both time and data in a Map. However, i still want to use the Vector.
Is there any way to achieve that second elements of Map shows the Vector but not waste any resource unnecessarily?

The first thing that comes to my mind is containing the adress of datas in Vector. However, pointers use 4 bytes(not sure) and for example, if we wanna contain the address of char, it is 4 times bigger than the data itself.

Any ideas ?

Comment: use a `std::set` instead of a `std::vector`. A set only allows a given item to be entered once. Or, you can use a hash map to retain the quick look up time while avoiding duplicates.

Comment: I dont have any problem with duplicates. I want to use the same data both in a vector and in a map, however, i dont want to have 2 copies of the same data. For example, if the map contains the real data, then the vector must contain some kind of alias to it, not the copy of it. The problem is, what kind of alias ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Use shared pointers then.

Comment: But think the case that i am storing the data with the type of "char". My data is just 1 byte, but the pointer is 4 bytes. My alias is 4 times bigger than my real data. So storing the copy of data is better in this case.

Comment: Your comment about being inefficient with pointers to characters makes me think of *template specialization* - in other words, have a generic template for all types, and use template specialization to specifically handle cases like `char`s (and even `bool`s can be packed as a bit string).

Comment: Since memory is expensive I would only keep one data struct.

Comment: If positions of elements in vector are constants, you can use those indexes to inderect access the metadata in the map container

Comment: I would store the data in one vector and the times in another. Put both of them in a class that manages insertions and deletions so that they are always in sync.

Comment: @marcp Thats the way which i finally decided to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's not solely a question of memory consumption, but of consistency also. Depends on how you're going to use various views on your original input data. In general I'd advise using `std::unique_ptr` for the original data and `std::weak_ptr` for reference in views.

But you're right that might have a certain memory usage overhead because of pointer sizes exceed size of the pointee objects.

For the latter case having a kind of [FlyWeight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) pattern implementation might be more appropriate.

Comment: Without significant work I don't see any solution fitting all his needs.

Comment: @andre Agreed! That's why I've mentioned the flyweight.

Answer (score 0):

> Containing single data in multiple containers

Yes, you can use [the Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to index the same data in more than one way with no duplication of content.  Unlike homebrew `XXX_ptr` solutions, the multi-index containers also takes care of keeping everything coherent (removing a data unit from the container automatically elides it from all indexes.)

Lighter weight, more specialized solutions (and possibly more efficient than either muklti-index containers and/or homebrew `XXX_ptr` solutions) may also be possible depending on your application's requirements, particularities and data insertion/lifecycle patterns:

- Do you need the memory layout of your original vector to remain unchanged, or can you accommodate a vector of some derived type?
- Will your vector contents change? can it grow?
- Will the elements therein be (inserted & kept) in chronological order anyway?
- Do you need to look up a vector element by insertion time in addition to vector position?